# Jquery and Sticky

Tags: php, sticky-post

I have a trouble with jquery and sticky in a div in my website.
I have included jQuery core in my page, inside the tag "head":

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Next, included the Sticky JS after the jQuery core:

```
<script src="js/stickySidebar.js"></script>
```

and I put inside it this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.one_fourth_style_4').stickySidebar();

});
```

But it's not working.
link: [my page](http://www.italiapokerblog.it/titanbet/)

Comment: As-written, this question appears to be quite similar to several other WPSE questions involving use of non-core-bundled versions of jQuery, failure to properly enqueue core-bundled jQuery **and custom scripts**, and failure to account for jQuery no-conflict configuration. Please **edit your question** to indicate that you have addressed all of these, and describe any remaining issues you observe once doing so.

Answer (score 0):

First, please use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add JavaScript to your WordPress pages.  Also note that jQuery is loaded by default in WordPress; there's no need for you to do it.

From that same page:

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode (see wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link.
>
> In the noConflict() mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available[...]
>
> However, if you really like the short $ instead of jQuery, you can use the following wrapper around your code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
        // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
    });
```

[[src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)]

So change your code to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.one_fourth_style_4').stickySidebar();
});
```

and it *should* work with WP's jQuery library.

Comment: it is not working :/ and the menu now is not also working

Comment: need I to load maybe a jquery plugin?

Comment: I've following this tutorial... http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/sticky-sidebar/ But I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Are you calling [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) in your theme's `header.php` and `footer.php` files (or their equivalents)?

Comment: of course.. I'm calling these files.